# Merge specific column data from all columns of csv where studentnumber is duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, import-csv

I have written a python script that takes bulk student data from our SIS, which shows complete class schedules for each student. Each class is on its own row, so each student will have multiple lines because they have multiple classes.  The script writes to a new csv file, only the data I am needing which is defined in the script to only look for certain class names.

This all works as expected, however.... In the final csv file, instead of there being multiple lines like this:

```
jane doe, 123456, Language arts, Teacherone@ourdomain.org
jane doe, 123456, Math, Teachertwo@ourdomain.org
Suzie Que, 321256, Math, Teachertwo@ourdomain.org
Suzie Que, 321256, English 101, Teacherthree@ourdomain.org
Johnny Appleseed, 321321, Language Arts, Teacherone@ourdomain.org
Johnny Appleseed, 321321, Math, Teacherone@ourdomai.org
```

I want the final csv file to look like this:

```
Jane doe, 123456, Language Arts; Math, Teacherone@ourdomain.org; 
Teachertwo@ourdomain.org

Suzie Que, 321256, Math; English 101, Teachertwo@ourdomain.org; 
Teacherthree@ourdomain.org

Johnny Appleseed, 321321, Language Arts; Math, Teacherone@ourdomain.org
```

I have looked into pandas, but just dont know how I would implement this.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

CODE BELOW:

```
        import csv

def ixl():
    with open(r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\pythonscripts\ixl\IXL 
CSV\IXL_DATA2.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        with open(r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\pythonscripts\ixl\IXL 
CSV\NEW_studentexport.csv', mode='w', newline='') as output_file:
            write = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', 
quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for row in csv_reader:
                Title = row[6]
                coursename = row[9]
                firstname = row[13]
                lastname = row[16]
                grade = row[14]
                studentnumber = row[17]
                studentidnumber = row[18]
                teacheremail = row[19]
                teacherfirst = row[20]
                teacherlast = row[21]
                stud_username = studentidnumber + "@highpointaca"
                password = int(studentnumber) + int(studentidnumber)


                if Title in ('Math 7', 'Albebra 1', 'Algebra 1 Honors', 
'Algebra 2', 'Algebra 2 Honors', 'Dual Enrollment College Algebra (MAT 
110', 
'Dual Enrollment English Comp. (ENG 102)' , 'Reading 5' , 'Pre-Calculus 
Honors' , 'Pre-Algebra8' , 'Pre-Algebra' , 'Mathematics' , 'Math K' , 
'Math 
7' , 'Math 6 Honors' , 'Math 6' , 'Math 5' , 'Math 4' , 'Math 3' , 'Math 
2' , 
'Math 1' , 'Language Arts 5', 'Language Arts 4', 'Language Arts 3', 
'Language 
Arts 2', 'Language Arts K', 'Language Arts 1', 'Language Arts', 'Geometry 
Honors', 'Geometry', 'Essentials of Math I', 'English 4', 'English 3', 
'English 2', 'English 1 Honors', 'English 1', 'ELA 7 Honors', 'ELA 6 
Honors', 
'ELA 8', 'ELA 7', 'ELA 6', 'Dual Enrollment English Comp. (ENG 101)'):

                    write.writerow([firstname, lastname, studentidnumber, 
grade, teacheremail, stud_username, password, Title])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ixl()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `csv` module and `collections.defaultdict`

**Demo:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

with open("input.csv") as infile:     #Read csv
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        result[row[0]].append(row)     #Group by name

final_result = []    
for k, v in  result.items():
    temp = v[0]
    for i in v[1:]:
        temp[2] += ", " + i[2]         #Concatenate subject names
    final_result.append(temp)

with open("output.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(final_result)         #Write back to csv
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me going!